# Rpi3 WIFI AP go down after some time of innactivity?

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, pi-3b+

I have setup my Rpi 3 as wifi access point and it was working for a long time. But some day, wifi stop working unexpectedly and i was no idea that what was the problem. It means wifi access point is showing on my lap and phone , but i am unable to connect to it.

I have not done anything to the configuration file and configuration was done by referring official documentation.

When i have this problem, I restarted the Rpi and I tried to connect my lap to the AP and it was worked at that time.

What will be the reason for frozen wifi AP? The problem solved by restarting it, but i want to know the reason?

Could you please help me?

Comment: inspect the system logs for any issues - alternatively, set up a cron job to reboot the pi at some convenient time every "some days"

Comment: Nothing was on syslog

Comment: sure, but what bout all the other log files?

Comment: I mean nothing is showed on the date, i was having problem

Comment: Is there any power controlling or any auto sleeping mode for Rpi 3?

Comment: sure, but it doesn't kick in after `some day`

Comment: From the info you have provided, it will not be possible for anyone to help you. Your problem could be caused by any number of issues, from power quality to ISP outages. You will need to narrow the range of potential causes if you want to fix this. For example, if you have an Internet service, you may want to try evaluating that [using one of these tools](http://www.dslreports.com/tools). And by the way, RPi has no sleep mode AFAIK.